# Objective C memory management question with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am loading an array with floats like this:

```
NSArray *arr= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.9],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.7],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.6],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.9],nil];
```

Now I know this is the correct way of doing it, however I am confused by the retail counts.

1. Each Object is created by the `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:]` method.  This gives the object a retain count of 1 dosnt it? - otherwise the object would be reclaimed
2. The `arrayWithObjects:` method sends a retain message to each object.

This means each object has a retain cont of 2.  When the array is de-allocated each object is released leaving them with a retain count of 1.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NSNumber numberWithFloat: method isn't returning a retained object.

In general unless you're using `alloc`, `copy` or `new` you can presume that you're getting a object that has a retain count of zero. As such the only retain that's taking place is when the NSArray has the objects added to it.

There's a good blog about such things over at: http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/

Comment: Ok thanks, ill read the blog.  How can the `NSNumber numberWithFloat:` method not return a retained object?  How could you implement a class method like this?

Comment: @Robert - NSNumber is simply returning an object, but you don't "own" it as you didn't create it yourself. (You could of course retain it if you wanted to.)

Comment: @Robert: You could implement it very simply like: +(id) numberWithFloat:(float)aFloat { return [[[self alloc] initWithFloat:aFloat] autorelease]; }

Comment: This answer is misleading. A better answer would be that [NSNumber numberWithFloat:] is returning an *autoreleased* object. It actually *does* return an object with a retain count of 1 (check it with gdb if you don't believe me), but `autorelease` has been called on it. The next time -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] is called, the object's retain count will be decremented by one. See "Memory Management Programming Guide" on Apple's developer site for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to release those objects.
The `arrayWithObjects:` and `numberWithFloat:` creates object you do not own.